# C# print file, wait for close file - program hang up

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I wrote program that listens on a directory (GUI - WPF). When the new file show up in this directory is sent to the printer. The problem occurs when I try to save a large file to this directory. I have to wait until the file is closed, and then send it to the printer. I have a function that checks if the file is open. But when I use it in the whole GUI hangs. How do I use this function asynchronously?

```
 protected void newfile(object fscreated, FileSystemEventArgs Eventocc)
        {
            try
            {
                    string CreatedFileName = Eventocc.Name;
                    FileInfo createdFile = new FileInfo(CreatedFileName);
                    string extension = createdFile.Extension;
                    string eventoccured = Eventocc.ChangeType.ToString();
                    fsLastRaised = DateTime.Now;

                        this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                        {
                            String file = "";
                            file = watchingFolder + "\\" + CreatedFileName;                                  
                            //printing
                            this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                            {
                                FileInfo info = new FileInfo(file);
                                while (!IsFileReady(info)) { }
                                var t = new Thread(() => printFile(file, extension)); //send to printer
                                t.Start();
                            }));

                        }));
                    }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error");
            }
        }
```

`IsFileReady` function:

```
 public static bool IsFileReady(FileInfo file)
        {
            FileStream stream = null;

            try
            {
                stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                //the file is unavailable because it is:
                //still being written to
                //or being processed by another thread
                //or does not exist (has already been processed)
                return true;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (stream != null)
                    stream.Close();
            }
            //file is not locked
            return false;
        }
```

And `printfile`

```
 public void printFile(string filepath, string ext)
        {
                    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
                    info.Verb = "print";
                    info.FileName = filepath;
                    info.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

                    Process p = new Process();
                    p.StartInfo = info;
                    p.Start();

                    p.WaitForInputIdle();
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);

                    if (false == p.CloseMainWindow())
                        p.Kill();

                }
        }
```

How can I correct this code to work with large files without hangs up?

EDIT:

For check new file I use `FileSystemWatcher`

```
private void start(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


            if (watchingFolder == null)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                fs = new FileSystemWatcher(watchingFolder, "*.*");
                fs.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                fs.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
                fs.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(newfile);
                btnSatrt.IsEnabled = false;
                btnStop.IsEnabled = true;

            }
        }
```

Comment: I use this class, @TimRutter I update my code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait Until File Is Completely Written](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982104/wait-until-file-is-completely-written)

Comment: while (!IsFileReady(info)) { } You should use some System.thread.sleep(xxx ms) insteed of running in a crazy loop  ?  The IsFileReady could also be run prior all other actions => new FileInfo(CreatedFileName);

Answer (score 1):

You're executing `while (!IsFileReady(info)) { }` through `Dispatcher.Invoke`, that executes the code on the UI thread so it will block for sure the app.

You aren't interacting at all with the UI, so the correct approach is to execute it asynchronously, via `Task`s and `await`s or with a background thread via the `ThreadPool` and not using at all `Dispatcher.Invoke`.

Comment: This is true but is there a way of configuring the FileSystemWatcher to only notify once the file is available.

Comment: Ok, but how to do this?

Comment: See the link I posted above - I'm not sure you can.

Comment: There's no real way to check with filesystemwatcher if the file has been completelly written, you can hook to the OnChanged event, but that can fire more than once for the creation of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute all code in the newfile event handler on a background thread by starting a new task:

```
protected async void newfile(object fscreated, FileSystemEventArgs Eventocc)
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            string CreatedFileName = Eventocc.Name;
            FileInfo createdFile = new FileInfo(CreatedFileName);
            string extension = createdFile.Extension;
            string eventoccured = Eventocc.ChangeType.ToString();
            fsLastRaised = DateTime.Now;

            string file = watchingFolder + "\\" + CreatedFileName;
            FileInfo info = new FileInfo(file);
            while (!IsFileReady(info)) { }
            printFile(file, extension);
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I try this. How cat I chage `while (!IsFileReady(info)) { }`? It's don't look good.

Comment: You can check whether the file exists using the File.Exists method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx. But you should still catch any excpetions that may occur. If the file actually exists you should be able to read it using a FileStream class even if the file is in use by another process: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759697/reading-a-file-used-by-another-process. But please ask a new question if you have another issue. Your original question was about not blocking the UI thread.

Comment: I get `task does not contain a definition for run` error with this code. Wrong .Net version?

Comment: Ok, I change .net to 4.5 but when file is created I get `the calling thread can not access this object because it belongs to another thread`

Comment: On what line are you getting this exception?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of Dispatcher.Invoke.