# File.Move on SND: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, windows-services, file-watcher

I have a file watcher windows service that moves a dropped file from folder A to folder B. File movement in this setup was successful, but when I shared the same folder and drop a file using the shared path, I always get an error indicating **The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.** Do note that I also tried accessing the shared path on the server itself and encountered the same error when dropping files. The event I use is **FileSystemWatcher.Changed.**

Comment: [Reading a file used by another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759697/reading-a-file-used-by-another-process) might be helpful if there isn't a read lock on the file.